# Can't access a session variable

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm using a session variable to keep track of the current site language, three values are possible, 1. EN, 2. RU, 3. ES.

the session variable is set initially in the config file:

```
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'RU';
```

but inside my db class I cannot access the variable. My basic understanding is that variables stored in the `$_SESSION` array are accessible throughout the site.
so what's the problem?

Comment: Have you started the session in your DB class before you try to access this session variable?

Comment: That was indeed what is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to call `session_start();` before using a session variables.

Answer (score 0):

Before instantiating the class, you need to open the session.
For example:

```
session_start('NAME_MY_SESSION')
```